# Function that copies parts of a file to another in C

Tags: c

I have to make a function which reads a file line by line and copies a some of them to another file. The head of the function has to look like this: "int write_x(const char *input_path, const char *output_path, int x)" and can't be changed. For example if x = 3 every third line of the input txt-file should be copied to the output txt-file. Every line has a maximum of 80 signs. I hope someone can help me because i'm not programming very long yet.
This is what I have alreaday, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int write_x(const char *input_path, const char *output_path, int x){
    input_path = "in.txt";
    output_path = "out.txt";
    FILE *in
    FILE *out
    char text[100];
    

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        fgets(text[i], 80, in);
        if(i % x == 0) {
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", text[i]);
        }
    }
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work... why not? What is the problem you're seeing? Any ideas why? What have you tried?

Comment: You are currently not using the parameter `x`.

Comment: The parameters `input_path` and `output_path` are also not used (overwritten without being read). Also there seems something missing (initialization and semicolon) after `FILE *in` and `FILE *out`.

Comment: Maybe if you print out each line after reading it, you will know whether the problem is reading or writing the line of text. Then, you will be able to search for documentation on the functions that you're using

Comment: Where has `in` been give a value before reaching `if( in == NULL ){`

Comment: Many problems which appear to be line oriented are not.  This is one of them.  You do not (and should not) need to read the file one line a time.  Read the file one character at a time, keeping track of the number of times you see `'\n'` and print each character as needed.  This overcomes any limitations on max line size.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't compile it (I'll leave that to you), but how about something like this?

Note that if your teacher penalizes for the use of 'goto', then you'll need to modify the error handling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int write_x(const char *input_path, const char *output_path, int x) {
    int result = 0 ;
    FILE * inputFile=NULL;
    FILE * outputFile=NULL;

    /* Open the input file for reading */
    inputFile = fopen( input_path, "r" ) ;
    if ( inputFile == NULL ) {
        perror( "fopen(input_path)" ) ;
        result = -1;
        goto clean_up;
    }

    /* Open the output file for writing */
    outputFile = fopen( output_path, "w") ;
    if ( outputFile == NULL ) {
        perror( "fopen(output_path)" ) ;
        result = -1;
        goto clean_up;
    }

    int lineNumber = 0 ;
    char * lineBuffer = NULL ; // memory will be allocated by getline()... but you'll need to free it up afterwards
    int lenBuffer ; // getline will set how bug the buffer is

    /* Repeat for each line read */
    while (getline( &lineBuffer, &lenBuffer, inputFile) != -1) {
        /* Only at each 'x' line count */
        if ( (++lineNumber % x ) == 0 ) {
            /* Write the line to the output file */
            if ( fwrite( lineBuffer, lenBuffer, 1, outputFile ) != lenBuffer ) {
                perror("fwrite");
                result = -1;
                goto clean_up;
            }
        }
    }

clean_up:
    /* avoid memory leak */
    if ( lineBuffer != NULL ) {
        free( lineBuffer ) ;
    }

    /* Close the input file */
    if ( inputFile != NULL ) {
        fclose( inputFile ) ;
    }

    /* Close the output file */
    if ( outputFile != NULL ) {
        fclose( outputFile ) ;
    }

    /* All done */
    return result ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a really bad design to be passing paths to this function as arguments instead of `FILE *`'s, but you're under no obligation to read the file line by line.  Just read one character at a time.  Something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
                                                                                   
FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);                                 
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
write_x(const char *input_path, const char *output_path, int x)                    
{                                                                                  
        FILE *in = xfopen(input_path, "r");                                        
        FILE *out = xfopen(output_path, "w");                                      
        int c;                                                                     
        int count = 1;                                                                                                                      
                                                                                   
        while( (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF ){                                           
                if( count == x ){                                                  
                        fputc(c, out);                                             
                }                                                                  
                if( c == '\n' ){                                                                                          
                        count = ( count % x ) + 1;                                 
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        return 0;                                                              
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(int argc, char **argv)                                                        
{                                                                                  
        int step = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1;                       
        char *in = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "in.txt";                                  
        char *out = argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "out.txt";                                
        write_x(in, out, step);                                                    
        return 0;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
FILE *                                                                             
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)                                         
{                                                                                  
        FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :         
                *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;                                     
        if( fp == NULL ){                                                          
                perror(path);                                                      
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return fp;                                                                 
}
```